# WSL-Debian won't start? Lingering WSL-Debian?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Via Apps (add/remove programs), I've removed WSL. I just found Windows Subsystem Linux in the list and clicked "uninstall".

When I go to cmd and type "`bash`", it puts me in Debian.

For some reason. Is this preventing me from accessing my WSL installation of Debian?

I use `wsl --install --distribution Debian` and end up with a version of Debian that won't start. If I type `wsl` in cmd, it just goes directly back to cmd:

[image: Prompt: user typed WSL; Prompt; user typed WSL again; Prompt...]

If I type `Debian`, same thing.

But if I type `bash`, I get kicked into a Debian install where I cannot change my root password and have forgotten my root password.

If someone knows how to reset the root password, let me know. Of course, `wsl ~ -u root -e chsh` gives me a password prompt, but I don't know the password so that's useless.

Also note: I cannot figure out how to uninstall the wsl that I'm getting kicked into when I type `wsl ~ -e chsh`. Maybe I could reinstall that one since I can at least enter it.

Comment: You can't reset root on Linux without the ability to go into a boot mode that doesn't exist with WSL. If your user is in the sudo group then you could in theory replace the password hash for root.  I assume you have tried `wsl --unregister Debian` before trying to reinstall Debian?

Comment: @Ramhound It's not *advisable* (see my answer for why), but it is possible to set or reset a root password on WSL with `wsl -u root -e passwd`.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds You need the root password for that to work. I think it's not possible to use admin priv in Windows to change the Debian WSL password: I wish I could force this to be possible. Instead, I am going to start using KeePass and just accept that my memory is twack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few things going on there ;-).

> Via Apps (add/remove programs), I've removed WSL. I just found Windows Subsystem Linux in the list and clicked "uninstall".
>
> When I go to cmd and type "bash", it puts me in Debian.

It's a bit of an odd situation, at least on Windows 10.  This occurs because there are actually *two* installations of WSL:

- The first is what's called the "in box" version of WSL.  Up until recently, this was the only WSL.  It's shipped with Windows and enabled in the *Turn Windows Features on or off* settings.  Under Windows 10 (but not Windows 11), it's actually required as a dependency of the other version ...
- Which is the *application package* version of WSL.  This is now the primary way to install WSL, and when you uninstalled it from the *Add or remove programs* settings, *this* is what was removed.  After it was removed, however, the older version still remained (and took over).

*Neither* of these is the Debian WSL distribution itself.  That's a separate installation.  Confused yet? ;-)

So you really should reinstall WSL from the Microsoft Store to make sure you have the latest.

> I use wsl --install --distribution Debian and end up with a version of Debian that won't start. If I type wsl in cmd, it just goes directly back to cmd:
>
> If I type `Debian`, same thing.
>
> But if I type `bash`, I get kicked into a Debian install

That is odd - `wsl` and `bash` should do the same thing, just with the `wsl` command providing more options.  However, the `bash` command is deprecated in WSL, so I can't say for sure what's happening here.

A `wsl -l -v` might show more than one distribution installed, but even that wouldn't account for exactly what you are seeing.

If you really do want to uninstall a distribution, as @Ramhound mentioned in the comments, you can use:

```
wsl --unregister <distro>
```

> where I cannot change my root password and have forgotten my root password.
>
> If someone knows how to reset the root password, let me know. Of course, `wsl ~ -u root -e chsh` gives me a password prompt, but I don't know the password so that's useless.

It sounds like you are looking for the `passwd` command rather than `chsh`.  The former changes the password, the later the default shell for a user.

That said, there *is* no initial password for `root` in most Linux distributions nowadays.  Your initial non-root user should be added to `sudoers` (again by default, even when not using WSL).  This is something that the WSL distribution installers do for you.  Having a root password is considered a bad security practice, since it gives root the ability to login without accountability or logging.

If you need to reset your *user* password (so that you can `sudo`), you can do that quite easily from PowerShell:

```
wsl -l -v # Confirm distribution name
wsl ~ -u root -d <distro> -e passwd <username>
```

If you don't know the default username, it's usually UID 1000, so you can find it (again from PowerShell) with:

```
wsl id -un 1000
```

Again, add the `-d <distro>` if needed.

> Of course, `wsl ~ -u root -e chsh` gives me a password prompt, but I don't know the password so that's useless.

I will say that's odd, though.  `chsh` as a root user doesn't ask for a password on my Debian installation under WSL.  That's the case even if I (pathologically) set a root password.

Comment: Okay. I did re-install (not for the reasons mentioned although they are very informative; rather, because a new Debian instance appeared in add-remove programs after restart). I also had to switch to WSL v1 (not sure why v2 doesn't work on my system anymore). I had trouble setting the initial root password (you have to login as root and then type passwd rather than using su - root because that requires a password and a blank password does not work). So, a lot of interesting things going on, but steps are being taken. I think your answer will work for most people. Thank you very much!